# SQL SELECT statement to pull data from multiple tables with foreign keys and associative relationships

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I have the following tables:

1. `Universities( iduni, uniname )`
2. `Campuses( idcampus, iduni, campusname, campusaddress )`
3. `Projects( idproject, idcampus, projectname )`
4. `IndustryCode( idindustrycode, codenumber, description )`
5. `Specialization( idspec, specname )`

The following are the associative tables for some of the above listed tables

1. `CampusSpecialization( idcampus, idspec )`
2. `ProjectSpecialization( idproject, idSpec )`
3. `ProjectIndustryCode( idproject,idindustrycode )`

And I want to generate XML file with the following structure via PHP, but can't figure out the `SELECT` statement to pull the data from the database. The data being the campuses, universities, projects, industry codes and specializations for each project so that when I can filter the results in my small application later on based on this interconnected data.

```
    <items>
        <item>
            <campus campusname="$CAMPUSNAME" uniname="$UNINAME" campusaddress="$CAMPUSADDRESS">
                <projects>
                    <project>
                        <name>$PROJECTNAME</name>
                        <specs>
                            <spec>$SPECNAME1</spec>
                            <spec>$SPECNAME2</spec>
                            ...
                        </specs>
                        <industries>
                            <industry>$CODENUMBER1</industry>
                            <industry>$CODENUMBER2</industry>
                            ...
                        </industries>
                    </project>
...
                </projects>
            </campus>
        </item>
        <item>
            <campus ... >
                <projects>
                    <project ... >
                        ...
                    </project>
            </campus>
    </items>
```

This is my SQL statment so far:

```sql
SELECT
  campusname, 
  specname,
  projectname
FROM
  Specialization,Projects
  JOIN CampusSpecialization ON CampusSpecialization.idspec = Specialization.idspec
  JOIN Campuses ON CampusSpecialization.idcampus = Campuses.idcampus
  JOIN ProjectSpecialization ON ProjectSpecialization.idspec = Specialization.idspec
```

**EDIT:**

Projects may have one or more codes and industries.

Comment: what was your problem/question?

Comment: I can't figure out the SQL statement to Select all the data from all the tables into one result set so I can use that to build the XML file with the structured outline above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```sql
SELECT c.campusname,u.uniname,c.campusaddress, s.specname, ic.codenumber, p.projectname
FROM campuses c
INNER JOIN universities u ON u.iduni = c.iduni
INNER JOIN camousspecialization cs ON cs.idcampus = c.idcampus
INNER JOIN speicialization s ON s.idspec = cs.idspec
INNER JOIN projectspecialization ps ON ps.idproject = s.idspec
INNER JOIN projectindustrycode pi On pi.idproject = ps.idproject
INNER JOIN industrycode ic on ic.industrycode = pi.industrycode
INNER JOIN projects p on p.idproject = ps.idproject
```

Comment: Hmm. `INNER JOIN projectspecialization ps ON ps.idproject = s.idspec` - having trouble here. It doesn't make sense to pair up project's ids with specilization's ids.

Comment: Hmm. There's only one campus that did any projects in my database but the results I get for some reason say that every campus did exactly the same projects three times.

Comment: @user1366451 - Can there multiple codes and spec names per project/campus? If so how do you want to handle it: return only one, return all, ...?

Comment: Yes, campus can have many projects done, and projects can have multiple codes and spec names. So, I want to return all campuses that have projects, but do not want return campuses that haven't done any projects which is the problem - all of the projects are getting paired up with campuses that are not even recorded in the database.

Comment: @user1366451 - As long you join projects and campus on the correct column ie `idcampus` you will get the correct results (see my example below). But the select will return multiple records for every project + code + spec name, which needs to be handled in code to generate the correct number of elements. I do not use php, so I do not the standard way to handle it there. You might be able to use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). See updated response

Comment: So I need to create an associative table between projects and campuses which would contain two columns - id of projects and id of campuses that did whichever project?

Comment: No, your existing tables should already tell you which projects are related to which campuses. If you are seeing the wrong pairings it suggests the sql is wrong. Try pulling only campus + project + university:  ie `SELECT  c.idCampus, c.campusName, c.campusAddress, u.uniName, p.projectName
FROM    Campuses c
            INNER JOIN Universities u ON u.iduni = c.iduni
            INNER JOIN Projects p ON p.idcampus = c.idcampus`

Comment: Hi Leigh. So, I went ahead and made an associative table anyways between campuses and projects and used your `SELECT c.idCampus, c.campusName, c.campusAddress, u.uniName, p.projectName FROM Campuses c INNER JOIN Universities u ON u.iduni = c.iduni INNER JOIN Projects p ON p.idcampus = c.idcampus` and it worked but i need to return 'specialization' and 'code' as well but when I do it returns 1000 records, when there is only 30..

Comment: @user1366451 - Hi. You should not need an associative table since you are already storing the campus id in the project table. Btw if you add a "@" symbol before someone's username they will get notified whenever you respond :)

Comment: You are welcome. If you found our responses helpful you can always upvote them :) I *think* up-voting is allowed for any reputation levels. But do not quote me on that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should pull all campuses with projects, and the *project's* codeNumber and specName.

Note, I am not completely sure about your schema. The associative tables imply there may be multiple codes and specNames per project. Whereas the xml implies there is only one of those per project. This query will return one record for each entry in your associative tables. ie If there are three (3) specifications for "Project A", the SELECT will return three (3) records.

```sql
SELECT  c.idCampus
        , c.campusName
        , c.campusAddress
        , u.uniName
        , p.projectName
        , s.specName as ProjectSpecName
        , ic.codeNumber AS ProjectCodeNumber
FROM    Campuses c
            INNER JOIN Universities u ON u.iduni = c.iduni
            INNER JOIN Projects p ON p.idcampus = c.idcampus
            INNER JOIN ProjectSpecialization ps ON ps.idproject = p.idproject
            INNER JOIN Specialization s ON s.idspec = ps.idspec
            INNER JOIN ProjectIndustryCode pic ON pic.idproject = p.idproject
            INNER JOIN IndustryCode ic ON ic.idindustrycode = pic.idindustrycode
```

**Edit:** Unfortunately, I do not use php. So I do not know the best or standard way to generate xml in php. You could possibly use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in your SELECT to return a concatenated list of the codes and names for each project. Then split those string into an array in php and use the array count to generate the desired number of xml elements.

```sql
SELECT  c.idCampus
        , c.campusName
        , c.campusAddress
        , u.uniName
        , p.projectName
        , GROUP_CONCAT(s.specName SEPARATOR '|') as SpecNameList
        , GROUP_CONCAT(ic.codeNumber SEPARATOR '|') AS CodeNumberList
       ...
```

Comment: Neat. I did not know there was sql highlighting. Thanks @Ben.

Comment: No problem @leigh, SO uses Google Prettify for mark-up but it's dependant on the tags in the question. As this has PHP at the beginning the site highlights PHP key-words; you can just switch it round it you want!

Comment: Nice. Learn something new every day :)

Comment: Oops. You are right. The project can have multiple codes and specs. But I use them in XML file as attribute only once. I'll edit the XML to reflect the codes and specs properly.